# Can the process of creating an module in zf2 be shortend?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am looking at a few tutorials and to just create 1 module you have to modify a bunch of configuration files in order to make the controllers, models, and views work. I see this as impossible to try and remember it all or comprehend what it is I’m doing. Is there an alternative method that creates these for me? so that i don’t have to write it all out every time i create a controller, or a module etc. I honestly don’t see how this is faster. I come from a codeigniter background so making this switch has me banging my head against the wall multiple times trying to comprehend.

Comment: Use the [zf-tool](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool) to quickly generate stuff. If you're finding ZF2 to be too complicated try something like [laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: thanks, i have to learn zf because a lot of companies require it. I’ll take a look at laravel some other time

Comment: i noticed that the zftool doesnt create the array data that goes into the configuration files. Is there an alternative?

Comment: hmm, haven't used zftool myself so I didn't realize it was kinda half-assed. You have to set the configs manually for now. Submit an issue with the project, this should really be part of creating the controller. although, you then have to create a route that corresponds with it. you'll just have to bite the bullet and learn how to do all this manually :p. get it down on paper, it's not a lot of steps.

Comment: I have the same thought when i start learning ZF2. What i can say is a few month after, its a really straight forward stuff and i dont even think about alooking for any tools, since is great to have control, and when you are familiar with everything, it looks like if it were much less work

Answer (score 0):

I've been using ZF2 for a few months now, and I've found that writing a class to generate that config for you is helpful.

There is no tool out there to do that for you. But if you follow the following approach, you should come right quite quickly:

```
class Configurator {
    public static function route($name, $url, $controller, $action='index') {
        return array(
            'router' => array(
                ...
            ),
        );
    }

    # Other static configuring methods

    ...
}
```

Then in your config you use the Configurator like this:

```
use Configurator;

return array_merge_recursive(
    array(
        'view_manager' => array(
            ...
        ),
    ),

    # Other top-level config
    ...

    Configurator::route('home', '/', 'Application\Controller\Index'),
    Configurator::route('other', '/other', 'Application\Controller\Other')
);
```

Your config is deep-merged by array_merge_recursive, utimately producing the config you want  with your own custom-built generators. You're at liberty to configure whole sets of config with one method, so you can create a resource *configurator* which sets up the controller invokables, the routes, and anything else required in one method.

**array_merge_recursive FTW!**

Enjoy! :)